# Partial Wakelock - Android System *backup* = NO deepsleep/doze mode

Tags: backup, 6.0-marshmallow, wakelock

I'm seeing following partial wake lock through [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats) (inside of *Partial Wakelocks*) and it seems that, this wake lock keeps my phone awake at all time and prevents deep sleep / doze mode(

> *backup* (Andriod System)

I'm using Huawei Nexus 6P (stock, rooted (no mods)) with latest Android 6.0.1 (MHC19Q).

Please advise.

---

*** UPDATE ***

I created following:

[Issue 207700 - android - Partial Wakelock - Android System *backup* = NO deepsleep/doze mode - Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207700)

---

workaround(s) (*NOT* fixes):

- `reboot` - temporarily address issue (until phone is plugged & unplugged to/from charger).
- `Settings` -> `Backup & reset` -> `Back up my data` -> Toggle `On` to `Off` - long(er) term solution, yet you're left *without* backup going forward...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but it occured after I had restored my phone from google backup. More precisely the "backup" wakelock appeared when I unplugged the phone from the charger. Thereafter the wakelock kicked in and remained doing so until I restarted the phone. But whenever I plugged in the charger, the wakelock came back again and another restart was a must-do.

How did I solved that? I just disabled the "back up my data" under "backup & reset", restarted the phone and enabled the "back up my data" again. At least for now the wakelock has not appeared again.

This was my trick.

Comment: after I restart my phone, that also goes away, but then it comes back later again...

Answer (score -1):

it's a general issue with Android 6.0, i also have this bug on my Galaxy S6 using ORO CSC and latest ROM (G920FXXS3DPE7 May-2016). It appears only after the phone is unplugged from charger and the backup app keeps the phone awake (not entering Deep Sleep). For the moment the only fix possible is to disable backup (Google "back up my data).